# Cuda, getting error when trying to allocate memory for integer in device

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, gpu

I am trying to pass in 2 2D arrays, 1 1D array and 2 integers to cudaMlloc() so that I can use it in my kernel. The 2D arrays are doubles and other is int.While the 1d array contains floats. I keep getting the error "no instance of overloaded function CudaMalloc matches the argument list.argument types are : (int,int).I dont know what I am doing wrong.
The kernel and the way i used it is below:

```
__global__ void getMatrix(double** cmatrix,int** data,float* angle,int x,int y){

int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

int xrad,yrad;
xrad = 0;
yrad = 0;

xrad = (int)round(cos(angle[i]) * (j+1) + x);   
yrad = (int)round(sin(angle[i]) * (j+1) + y);   

cmatrix[i][j] = (double)data[yrad-1][xrad-1];

}
```

And the implementation is:

```
int dataFileSize = 801 * 1201 * sizeof(int);
int cmatrixSize = ANGLESIZE * RADIUS/RADSTEP * sizeof(double);
int xVarSize = sizeof(int);
int yVarSize = sizeof(int);

int** d_data;
cudaMalloc(&d_data,dataFileSize);

double** d_cmatrix;
cudaMalloc(&d_cmatrix,cmatrixSize);

float * d_angle;
cudaMalloc(&d_angle,sizeof(float) * ANGLESIZE);

int *d_x;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x,xVarSize);
int *d_y;
cudaMalloc((void**)d_y,yVarSize);

cudaMemcpy(d_data,data,dataFileSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_cmatrix,cmatrix,cmatrixSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_angle,angle,sizeof(float) * ANGLESIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_x,&x,xVarSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_y,&y,yVarSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);         

const dim3 blockSize(ANGLESIZE,1,1);
const dim3 threadSize(1,RADIUS/RADSTEP,1);

getMatrix<<<blockSize,threadSize>>>(d_cmatrix,d_data,d_angle,d_x,d_y);

cudaMemcpy(cmatrix,d_cmatrix,cmatrixSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_data);
cudaFree(d_cmatrix);
cudaFree(d_angle);
cudaFree(d_x);  
cudaFree(d_y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mentioning an error with `cudaMalloc`

This line is not correct:

```
int *d_y;
cudaMalloc((void**)d_y,yVarSize);
```

it should be:

```
int *d_y;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_y,yVarSize);
                   ^
                   add this ampersand
```

although you've hidden that error from the compiler by your `(void **)` cast, so that is not what the compiler is flagging.

You cannot allocate 2D arrays like this with `cudaMalloc`:

```
int** d_data;
cudaMalloc(&d_data,dataFileSize);

double** d_cmatrix;
cudaMalloc(&d_cmatrix,cmatrixSize);
```

And these will throw compiler errors, because `cudaMalloc` expects a `**` argument, not `***`.

It's recommended that you flatten those arrays and pass them as 1D arrays, and if needed do subscript arithmetic in your kernel to simulate 2D.  If you really want to learn how to pass a 2D array, search on CUDA 2D array to get some ideas.

Whether there are other errors in your code is difficult to say since you have not provided a complete code.